# How do i make safari prevent search on addresses?

Tags: safari

I have an internal server at the address `http://myserver`.
If I type `myserver/page` safari starts a google search. How can I disable this behavior?

I know I can prefix `http://` and it will start working, but other browsers lets me just type the address and takes me there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if you add a slash `/` at the end of the address, it won't search and it's easier than `http://` at the beginning.